# ExpandingTextareas Initialize Error when in Foundation Reveal

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [ExpandingTextareas plugin](https://github.com/bgrins/ExpandingTextareas), and I have a [foundation reveal ajax](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) call to load some data, and on document ready I'm using `$("#foo").expanding();` but I'm getting the following error

> ExpandingTextareas: attempt to initialize an invisible textarea. Call
>   expanding() again once it has been inserted into the page and/or is
>   visible.

How can I get this to find the dynamically added data? If I check the source code the textarea is definitely there.

I've tried adding a delay to the initialization but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/bgrins/ExpandingTextareas/issues/50#issuecomment-64323178) you’ll need to call `expanding()` on the `opened.fndtn.reveal` event to ensure that the textarea is in the DOM.